# How do you return a reference of a method with Func<>?

Tags: c#

I have a simple bit of code but am struggling to work out the correct syntax to return the method as a reference so it can be used.

This is what i am trying to do:

```
    public static Func<float> GetFunction(Functions functions)
    {
        switch (functions)
        {
            case Functions.Linear: return // how do i return the func here?
                break;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public static float Linear(float k) // am trying to return this
    {
        return k;
    }
```

The idea then is i will be able to do something like:

```
Func<float> func = GetFunction(Functions.Linear);
print func(10);
```

I am not sure how i create the return though.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate

Comment: Oh so func was not the right choice ? Seems it's more complicated than i first thought.

Comment: @WDUK `Func<float>` is a type of delegate.  But if you want something that takes and returns a float then you want `Func<float, float>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a delegate to `float Linear(float k)`, a function that takes a `float` argument and has a `float` return value, the generic `Func<float, float>` delegate would have to be used instead of `Func<float>`, which encapsulates a function that takes no argument and returns a `float`. As in:

```
public static Func<float, float> GetFunction(Functions functions)
{
    switch (functions)
    {
        case Functions.Linear: return Linear;
            break;
        default: return null;
    }
}

public static float Linear(float k) // am trying to return this
{
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Ah damn i had put `return Linear` but it wasn't compiling, was my `Func<float>` that was wrong. Thanks for that :)